# Issue with executing Powershell commands

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute the following commands in Microsoft Powershell console (with Administrator right):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
$userCredential = Get-Credential
$sfbSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $userCredential
Import-PSSession $sfbSession
```

The first three commands are executed without any issue but when I try to execute `$sfbSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $userCredential` I'm getting the following error:

```
New-CsOnlineSession : The term 'New-CsOnlineSession' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:15
+ $sfbSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $userCredential
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-CsOnlineSession:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried to look on various online forums but it's not solving my issue. On Microsoft's website they say that we have to use `MicrosoftTeams` module instead of `SkypeOnlineConnector` module but it's not working in my case. I tried various steps but all in vain. I hope someone got an idea how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Regards,

Seeya

Comment: please add code formatting markers around your code/data/errors. the how-to is linked on the page you used to create your Question.

Comment: Not sure if that means that command was actually removed from the module, but here goes: "With Teams PowerShell Module `New-CsOnlineSession` has been deprecated and is no longer required to connect Skype for Business Online. It has been replaced with `Connect-MicrosoftTeams`." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/new-csonlinesession?view=skype-ps

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the link. I'm using a Powershell script provided by a developer. They told me if I'm using the new Teams PowerShell Module, it will work. I requested them to modify their script but they haven't done it yet.

Comment: If you're using the new Teams Powershell Module, it will not work. It has been deprecated, as @mklement0 noted earlier. `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` is the way to go here.